# Change modifiers to final in netbeans

Tags: java, eclipse, netbeans

Is there any equivalent command in Netbeans for Eclipse's "Change modifiers to final where possible"?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any such refactoring in NetBeans. It does not sound difficult to write as an editor hint; somewhat similar hints exist: [FieldEncapsulation.java](http://hg.netbeans.org/main-silver/raw-file/default/java.hints/src/org/netbeans/modules/java/hints/encapsulation/FieldEncapsulation.java)